# Iterate through and show the values in a 2D array taken from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Hi I am new to 2D arrays and I am having problems with showing the content of the array indexes. I am reading the values from a text file and storing them into a 2D array. I am not sure if the items are even storing properly. When I use a System.println() during the iteration of the 2D array being filled then it prints all the values out as they currently show up. However if I try filling the array and call any location index after such as data[45][45]; it will only return a 0. Each int value taken from the text file that should be stored are each in the millions.

```
final String FILENAME = "DATA.TXT";

int [ ][ ] data = null;

int numberOfRows = 0;
int numberOfCols = 0;
String message ="";

try {
    File file = new File(FILENAME);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    // Read the number of Rows and Columns first
    numberOfRows = inputFile.nextInt();
    numberOfCols = inputFile.nextInt();
    //Creates the row and column amount
    data = new int[numberOfRows][numberOfCols];

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < data[5].length; j++)
        {
            while(inputFile.hasNextInt())
            {
                data[i][j] = inputFile.nextInt();
                //System.out.println(data[i][j]); //This works for displaying the values cuurently
            }
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading data from " + FILENAME + 
        " Exception = " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Data has been read - file has " + numberOfRows + 
    " rows and " + numberOfCols + " columns.");

//THIS or even using a loop to iterate through the 2D array that should contain 
// the values does not appear and only ends up as 0 as if the values are not stored.
System.out.print(data[56][56]);
}
}
```

I have looked at this for a few hours and I do not understand if the values are not being stored properly or if there is a reason I cannot call the value in any index of data such as data[45][45] or using a loop such as

```
for(int n =0; n <data.length; n++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < data[0].length; k++)
    {
        System.out.print(data[n][k]);
    }
}
```

If I am doing this completely wrong or there is a much more efficient way to do this please let me know. Otherwise in general I do not know what is wrong.

Thank you for checking out my post and I believe this would be helpful to many new programmers to 2D arrays and file read.

FILE CONTENTS

500 1000
1052662 1025260 1064342 1045596 1093363 1063663 1014129 1070544 1005352 1046317 1059536 1009817 1049327 1012134 1047499 1026392 1056558 1098823 1060554 1028017 1046977 1022098 1018538 1077771 1082687 1025653 1056869 1076473 1097420 1080444 1063797 1014295 1083251 1037760 1026325 1003914 1034680 1069524 1029877 1075546 1047177 1061381 1080359 1035442

Comment: Mind posting the file contents?

Comment: I posted some of the file contents, the rest just continues like that. There are 20 000 records I think

Comment: Your loop is not right. It reads all the values from the file in your 'while', but none of the 'for' loop increment until all the values are read. So data[i][j] = inputFile.nextInt() always stores the read ints in data[0][0], after that in data[1][0]  and so on

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. The while is the problem? Without it it gave me a outofboundsexception

Comment: maybe because i < data.length should be i<numberOfRows and j < data[5].length should be j<numberOfCols but is just a guess

Comment: I tried that but they are the same, data.length counts the number of rows which is 500 same as numberOfRows anyways

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String FILENAME = "d:/data.txt";

        long[][] data=null;

        int numberOfRows = 0;
        int numberOfCols = 0;
        String message = "";

        try {
            File file = new File(FILENAME);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            // Read the number of Rows and Columns first
            numberOfRows = inputFile.nextInt();
            numberOfCols = inputFile.nextInt();
            // Creates the row and column amount
            data = new long[numberOfRows][numberOfCols];

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfCols; j++) {

                        data[i][j] = inputFile.nextInt();


                }
            }
            inputFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading data from " + FILENAME
                    + " Exception = " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Data has been read - file has " + numberOfRows
                + " rows and " + numberOfCols + " columns.");

    // display 2D array

        for(int n =0; n <numberOfRows; n++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < numberOfCols; k++)
            {
                System.out.print(data[n][k] +"  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, without the while statement it will error out. And with the rest of your modifications it just gives me all 0's again.

Comment: create a file `data.txt` in your `d drive` , put some value and just run and check it will work definitely..

Comment: first two number are `numberOfRows` and `numberOfCols` so just make sure number of value must be greater or equal to `numberOfRows*numberOfCols` i.e if if first two numbers are 5 and 5   then your file must contain 27 or more values;

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question. When i call locations in data outside the try catch it only brings back 0, inside the try catch during the reading of the data.txt file it works

Comment: what do you mean by 'When i call locations in data outside the try catch it only brings back 0' ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out I just had to get rid of the while statement and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks for all your help tho.